# python3 mapping the unique value between two files and merge the unique lines from both files

Tags: python-3.x

I'm figuring out the unique values between two files and wants to megre the lines from both files into one line if the unique values exists into both files.

More explicitely, i'm looking for `MAC ADDRESS` that's column three in the `file1` making that a key and wants to match it over `file2` and if that matches then merge both the file's matches into one line.

file1

```
192.168.100.1            0  001c.0718.1ed6  Vlan100, Port-Channel230
192.168.100.2            0  fa16.3e88.245d  Vlan100, Port-Channel230
192.168.100.3            0  001c.0718.1f52  Vlan100, Port-Channel230
192.168.100.4            0  001c.0724.tb6a  Vlan100, Port-Channel51
192.168.100.5            0  01c.0718.1t9c   Vlan100, Port-Channel230
192.168.100.6            0  fa16.3ed8.dd6c  Vlan100, Port-Channel27
192.168.100.7            0  fa16.3e22.20c3  Vlan100, Port-Channel230
192.168.100.8            0  fa16.3ecd.e1db  Vlan100, Port-Channel27
192.168.100.9            0  001c.0718.9c8f  Vlan100, Port-Channel230
```

file2

```
   4    001c.0724.tb6a    DYNAMIC     Po17       1       13 days, 22:08:51 ago
   4    001c.0718.1f52    DYNAMIC     Po15       1       12 days, 5:07:20 ago
   4    001c.0718.1ed6    DYNAMIC     Po11       1       12 days, 5:05:44 ago
   4    001c.0718.1t9c    DYNAMIC     Po9        1       12 days, 5:07:16 ago
   4    001c.0718.9c8f    STATIC      Po9        1       12 days, 5:07:16 ago
```

Code : Below is the code which i tried based on the pattern and fit from the examples i found from googles, but it throws the error while executing it.

```
!#/usr/bin/python3
# port_details.py
    mapping_dict = {}

    INPUT_FILE_1 = 'file1'
    INPUT_FILE_2 = 'file2'
    with open(INPUT_FILE_1) as file1:
        while True:
            line = file1.readline()
            print(line)
            if not line:
                break
            #_, mac, _, port = line.strip()
            ip_addr, _, mac, _, status = line.split()

            mapping_dict[mac.lower()] = status

    with open(INPUT_FILE_2) as file2:
        while True:
            line = file2.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            #ip_addr, _, mac, _ = line.strip()
            _, value_id, _, port = line.split()
            status = mapping_dict.get(mac, '')
            print(ip_addr, mac, port, status)
```

Error While running, i tried diffrent values for the error but didn't get it running still looking around, any hint or suggestion will be much appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./srdjan1.py", line 13, in <module>
    ip_addr, _, mac, _, status = line.split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)
```

Desired Value Would Be:

```
192.168.100.1   001c.0718.1ed6  Po11 Vlan100 Port-Channel230
```

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive... You have 5 whitespace-separated fields in each row, but you're only handling 4 of them.

Comment: @glibdud, i tried putting `_` value to handle the space but then it says `expected 6, got 5`.

Comment: That likely means it advanced to another row that had 5 whitespaces instead of 4. Your file format is not consistent enough to split on generic whitespace. It looks like each column starts on the same index in each row, so maybe use that instead of `split()`.

Comment: @glibdud, i'll try that to see if kickstart the logic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, using dictionary to hold the values along with `re` for whitespaces.

```
import re

INPUT_FILE_1 = 'file1.txt'
INPUT_FILE_2 = 'file2.txt'

dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}

def fl2():
    with open(INPUT_FILE_2) as file2:
        while True:
            line = file2.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            data1 = re.split("\s+",line)
            dict1[data1[2]] = data1[4]
        file2.close()
        return dict1

with open(INPUT_FILE_1) as file1:
    dict2 = fl2()
    while True:
        line = file1.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        data = re.split("\s+",line)
        if data[2] in dict2:
            print(data[0],data[2],dict2[data[2]])
```

result as expected:

```
./port_details.py
192.168.1.1 001001c Good
```